# Stackdriver Retention policy is 30 Days .How Stackdriver dashboards have managed to show data from last 6 weeks?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Stackdriver Retention policy is 30 Days .How Stackdriver dashboards have managed to show data from last 6 weeks ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods), Admin activity and access transparency both have retention periods much longer than 30 days. However, the graphs are based off of Stackdriver Monitoring which has a metrics retention [policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#data_retention_policy) of 6 weeks